# Maui XAML: Elements are positioned at top and buttom of vertical stack layout

Tags: xaml, maui

Ive been working with xamarin for years now, and I know THIS code should work:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Skillbased.Pages.LogIn.CreateAccount.Page_Tutorial"
             Title="Page_Tutorial">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid Margin="0,30,0,0">        
                <Image Source="img_headerbar"/>
                 <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
                       FontFamily="BebasNeue"
                       FontSize="30"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       Text="WARUM SKILLBASED?"/>
            </Grid>
            <Image VerticalOptions="Start" Source="img_bike"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

But the result is this:

[image]

And no, the picture at the bottom does not have a big white space ontop of it.

I even tried this with a grid, but stil, it is positioned at the bottom. What on earth is happening here?

EDIT:

Oh and if I tried to deploy on android:

[image]

.. things work out, but ofc, the font doenst load right on android here... anyway, seems the issue is why maui

Comment: Yeah i did grid on outter most, I also did verticalstacklayout. neither work, and this issue is only on ios (as you can see in my edit). This issue also does not exist with other pictures that do not go full across the screen

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment after your edit, because it wasn't really applicable anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a width to the element.

```
<Image Source="img_manwithbike.png" HeightRequest="260"/>
```

Then using this inside a verticalstacklayout did the trick. Not sexy, but for now it suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have a `Grid` completely on the outside and place the `ScrollView` inside of it. Then use a `VerticalStackLayout` and position it at the Start *(the "Expand" options from Xamarin.Forms don't exist anymore in .NET MAUI)*.

Does this work for you?

```xml
<Grid>
  <ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
      Spacing="0"
      Margin="0"
      VerticalOptions="Start">

      <Grid Margin="0,30,0,0"
            VerticalOptions="Start">
        <Image Source="img_headerbar"/>
        <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
               FontFamily="BebasNeue"
               FontSize="30"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Text="WARUM SKILLBASED?"/>
      </Grid>
      <Image VerticalOptions="Start" Source="img_bike"/>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thank you, but the result is 100% identical. the picture on ios is rendered at the bottom. if i use another picture that is not full in witdh it works but thats no option

Comment: Have you searched for this issue in the GitHub repository of MAUI already? https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Comment: yeah i went through this, this was not put up yet. anyway I have decided to create a few tickets, as there are many issues (linehuight is broken on labels, custom font doesnt load, this issue here...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the VerticalOrientation property on StartAndExpand. Does the Image move or if you set it to Center?

I would also set the backround of both images to red or something. With this you can see if iOS maybe expand them.

My last idea would be to set the Grid.RowDefinition.

Answer (score 0):

I give you some suggestions:

1. Set the image **WidthRequest** or use image **Aspect** property
2. Use **Grid** as outer control. Set RowHeight for the row.
3. Try using **AbsoluteLayout**. To position and size children, you could use **AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds**.For more information, you could refer to [AbsoluteLayout in .NET Maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout?view=net-maui-7.0)